# How to format multiple OR condition?

Tags: c, do-while, logical-operators, logical-or

I am looking at doing a multiple OR condition at the end of a `do..while()` loop and I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

What I have right now is as follows:

```
do
{
    (Insert code here)
}while(x != ('a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u');
```

Is this going to work or should I write it differently?

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative to the explicit individual tests correctly described in the other answers, you might find it more concise/expressive to use [strchr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr):

```
do
{
    ...
} while (strchr("aeiou", x) == NULL);
```

Comment: I like this one, I wanted one that was concise but wasn't sure how to do it. I haven't used strchr before but now I see what it does :)

Comment: This code is not 100% equivalent to the equality tests: it may produce false positives if `x` is not in the range `-128..255`. But if `x` is a `char` or the return value of `getc()`, it is a viable and readable solution.

Comment: @chqrlie: you're right, I was assuming that `x` is a `char`, but you have to be careful about assumptions!

Answer (score 5):

That will not do what you want. You actually want:

```
do // note the lowercase d
{
    (Insert code here)
}while(x != 'a' && x != 'e' && x != 'i' && x != 'o' && x != 'u');
```

You can use parentheses to make the priorities obvious, like `while((x != 'a') && (x != 'e'))`.

However, if you do these checks often and with many possible letters, you should look into (bit-)sets, and just check if x is in that set. (EDIT: or as PaulR suggests, `strchr`)

---

EDIT: What you originally wrote will do something completely different. The expression

```
(x != ('a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u'))
```

first evaluates both sides of `!=` then compares them. The left side is `x`, while the right side is actually `1`. `||` is a binary operator, and returns `1` if either the left side or the right side of it is `!=0`, which it is. So it would see that `'a'!=0`, and stop evaluating others (because it can already calculate the result, it will optimize it away). So the condition is actually `while (x != 1)`.

Comment: bit sets? I haven't heard of these before. Any idea where I can read up on this?

Comment: @PaigeAngels Implementation explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array   C++ STL implements them, so you can look around there as well: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/

Answer (score 2):

`'a'` is an *expression* that evaluates to non-zero. (It's actually the ASCII value of the lower case letter `a`.)

So `'a' || 'b'` is also non-zero, and so on. In fact, the expression `'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u'` is probably evaluated at compile time: check the machine code.

If you need to test the value of `x` against a set of character literals, then you need to write something like

`x != 'a' && x != 'e' && x != 'i' && x != 'o' && x != 'u'`

Personally I'd be inclined to build a function `isVowel`, and use that as your `while` condition. That could help with scalability.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not going to work because in your code, `('a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u')` will be evaluated first which returns a boolean value, and its comparison with `x` does not make any sense.

I think this is what you are trying to do

```
do
{
// (Insert code here)
}while(x!='a' && x!='e' && x!='i' && x!='o' && x!='u');
```